# how can i encrypt my string with hmac and sha1 in jquery?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, hmacsha1

I am sending my form data using ajax to third party server using web services but in that i need encrypt my data like this

```
hmac("sha1", "12345-Aeff", JSON.stringify(msgdata));
```

In `msgdata` i have a value like this

```
var msgdata ={
    "contactID" : contactid,
    "fileName" : file_name,
     "fileSize":check_size,
     "fileTicketID":fileticktid,     
     "token" :token
}
```

Is there possible to encrypt `"msgdata"` like above example in hmac and using sha1?

Comment: hmacsha1 hashes, it does not encrypt.  Easiest/most resilient way is to post your json to a server side script, generate the hash (E.g. hash_hmac() in PHP) and then post from there.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You just have to find a library that supports this. Hint: jQuery does not.